# Loading Excel data into SQL server - Extra NULL Rows added

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I'm trying to import data from an Excel sheet into a sqlserver database. I used the sample code that is in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/636719/Import-MS-Excel-data-to-SQL-Server-table-using-Csh). However, when an import is made extra 22 rows with NULL values are being copied. I'm not sure how to remove the NULL values.

[image: Database screen shot]

Comment: Still not sure why the NULL values are being copied and exactly 22 rows each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the select statement, try adding a WHERE clause to exclude the nulls.
EX.

```
select student,rollno,course from [sheet1$]
```

Becomes:

```
select student,rollno,course from [sheet1$] where student IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
    while (dr.read())
    {
        bulkcopy.writetoserver(dr);
    }
```

you could check `dr` to see whether all of the columns are null, and if so skip the call to `bulkcopy.writetoserver()`.